# Allow non-admin users to create projects

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm looking to allow non-admin users to create their own projects, i've found the option to set the default role for a non-admin who has created a project, but I cant find how to let them actually create the project, do I have to set a role for them somewhere? or is there a plugin I have to install?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's there but not very intuitive. In order to have permissions in Redmine a user must be a member of a project first.

1. Give a Role the "Add Project" permission
2. Add the user as a Member to a project with that Role
3. Then the user should be able to see the "Add Project" link on the cross project list (/projects)

Comment: Cheers, I found it after a few hours of trial and error, it seems odd that to give someone the ability they need to be a manager, perhaps a better way would be to create a role specifically for creating projects or something similar, cheers again

Comment: I agree, we're trying to think of a better way to manage permissions outside of a project but it's a lot of code to replace.

Comment: @EricDavis Is there any progress on that? I've just googled for the same and came to this SO question.

Answer (score 7):

As of 2015 and Redmine 3.0 the answer to the question is rather simple and intuitive.

Go to:
Administration > Roles and permissions > Non member

Check the "Create project" checkbox and save.

I realize the question is old, but I stumbled upon it from google, so it might help anyone in doubt it is that easy.

Comment: Nice! however this would mean everyone would be able to create projects which is not desirable

Comment: The way is odd but works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this looking for an answer to something else.

To help the documentation here, I will repeat what is on the [RedMine wiki page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/):

### Enabling unknown users to create issues by email

Redmine has a feature that provides the ability to accept incoming emails from unknown users. In order to use this feature, an extra parameter has to be included:

```
unknown_user=ACTION     how to handle emails from an unknown user where ACTION can be one of the following values:
                    ignore: the email is ignored (default)
                    accept: the sender is considered as an anonymous user and the email is accepted
                    create: a user account is created for the sender (username/password are sent back to the user) and the email is accepted
```

Permissions have to be consistent with the chosen option. E.g. if you choose 'create', the 'Non member' role must have the 'Add issues' permission so that an issue can be created by an unknown user via email. If you choose 'accept', the 'Anonymous' role must have this permission.

If you receive emails via the rake task, the unknown-user option has to be written as:

```
unknown_user=[ignore|accept|create]
```

You can disable permission checking using the 'no_permission_check' option:

```
no_permission_check=1   disable permission checking when receiving the email
```

This, together with the 'unknown-user', provides the ability to let anyone submit emails to a private project. For example:

```
rdm-mailhandler --unknown-user accept --no-permission-check --project=foo
```

will let anyone submit emails to a private project 'foo'.

TODO: Is this true and is this related to the no_permission_check option?:

> Since Redmine 0.9 the project doesn't have to be public, but authentication required in the Administration-> Settings->Authentication tab has to be unchecked.

If you do not want an "new account notification email" sent to every newly created user by rdm-mailhandler you must add the option "--no-account-notice". Is implemneted with 2.3.0 in issue #11498. Now an example:

```
rdm-mailhandler --unknown-user accept --no-permission-check --project=foo --no-account-notice
```

[REFERENCE](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails#Enabling-unknown-users-to-create-issues-by-email)